# how to find a test for detecting fluctuation in a time series?

Tags: time-series, p-value, trend

I have a time series which consists of, say, 100 values (which comes from a loss function).

Normally, the loss goes down over iterations. However, at some point it just starts fluctuating.

I would like to have a way to detect when the loss is simply fluctuation and not actually going down.

The way I am doing this currently is the following:
I take my interval of 100 values, compute the median and split in half. Then I look at the proportion of value in the first interval which are bigger than the median and compute a p-value using a binomial test with H_0: p = 1/2 (with n_successes = number of values bigger than median, n = 50).

Any ideas? thank you

Comment: consider using time series analysis methods such as arima modelling with intervention detection to deal with anomalies..

Comment: thanks for the answer, what would count as anomalies though? I don;t think I am dealing with said anomalies in my case

Comment: an anomalie is something that is not part of the model. It reflects unusual readings THOUGH  real. An anomalie (after investigation) can sometimes lead to a cause for this latent structure. If you have the actual values (not the sum) that have been observed this would be the place to start.Post an example (real or simulated) of your data and perhaps you can get more detailed help here.